# Incorrect ruby version when installing through RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I'm trying to learn Ruby, and one of the most common ways I found of installing it is through [RVM](http://rvm.io/). After running `rvm install 2.1.2` to get the latest version it seems to complete fine, but when doing `ruby -v` this output is shown:

> chris@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
>   ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

which is the wrong version. Doing `rvm list` shows only 2.1.2:

> chris@ubuntu:~$ rvm list
>   rvm rubies
>   =* ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]

Doing a `rvm reinstall 2.1.2` also completes fine, however I still end up with the wrong Ruby version installed. Here's the output for that:

```
chris@ubuntu:~$ rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.2
ruby-2.1.2 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.1.2..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.1.2 - #configure
ruby-2.1.2 - #download
ruby-2.1.2 - #validate archive
ruby-2.1.2 - #extract
ruby-2.1.2 - #validate binary
ruby-2.1.2 - #setup
ruby-2.1.2 - #gemset created /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
ruby-2.1.2 - #importing gemset /home/chris/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems....................................
ruby-2.1.2 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.1.2 - #gemset created /home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
ruby-2.1.2 - #importing gemsetfile /home/chris/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.1.2 - #generating default wrappers........
Making gemset ruby-2.1.2 pristine........................................................................
Making gemset ruby-2.1.2@global pristine...............................................................
```

Comment: if you have ruby installed in the system it might be the problem, try `sudo apt-get remove ruby`

Comment: I'm suspecting you need to set e.g. ```rvm use --default 2.1.2```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
rvm use <your ruby version>
```

install only installs it.  It doesn't use it.

Comment: That's it, thanks. I assumed it was already "using" that version as it was listed as the default under `rvm list`. Thanks again :)